# How to enable ipv6 on alpine docker image?

Tags: linux, docker, ipv6, alpine-linux

I just discovered that using alpine docker image I don't have ipv6, see

```
sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep disable_ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

My question is how I can run alpine with enabled support for ipv6?

Comment: Did you do that: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Configure_Networking#Enabling_IPv6_.28Optional.29 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable ipv6 in the docker daemon in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
add : { "ipv6": true }
```

Then reload the docker daemon. "systemctl reload docker"